# How to include FMX.Types inside a VCL project

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to call `Log.d` that is defined inside FMX.Types. However my project is not a Firemonkey project, it's a VCL project. It compiles and works as expected but I receive this warning :

> [dcc64 Hint] H2161 Warning: Duplicate resource:  Type 12 (CURSOR
>   GROUP), ID 32761; File c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Win64\release\FMX.Controls.Win.res
>   resource kept; file c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Win64\release\Controls.res resource
>   discarded.

Is their any global define that could indicate that the project is a VCL project so that I can omit to use FMX.Types and `Log.d` on VCL project ?

Comment: What is the question. Do you want to detect that the project is FMX? Or do you want to include FMX units in a VCL project? You appear to ask both. Please ask one question only.

Comment: any of theses ! because they are both a solution to my problem. so detect that the project is FMX (to exclude fmx unit from the project)  -- or -- any way to include a fmx units in a vcl project

Comment: Please pick one. You can't ask two questions in one. To help you pick one though, I can tell you that there is no conditional that identifies a project as being FMX.

Comment: May I recommend side-stepping the entire issue by simply calling `OutputDebugString` instead of worrying about calling `Log.d`, thereby negating the need to pull in that FMX unit? `Log.d` calls `OutputDebugString` on Windows - you could easily make a wrapper routine that took similar parameters to `Log.d`. The conundrum then vanishes.

Comment: @blong: perfect solution thanks !! Just sad you wrote it as a comment because it's deserve to be an acceptable solution ...

Comment: @Vyacheslav - I had posted an answer with some sample code, in case you wish to follow up and mark this question as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a little on my comment, you could sidestep the whole problem by simply "brewing your own" `Log.d` equivalent. `Log.d` calls `OutputDebugString` on Windows, so you could build something along the following lines and leave the FMX.Types helper unit entirely out of the equation, and avoiding the problem entirely:

```
uses Windows;

procedure Log(const Msg: string; const Args: array of const); overload;
var
  LMsg: string;
begin
  LMsg := Format(Msg, Args);
  OutputDebugString(PChar(LMsg));
end;

procedure Log(const Msg: string); overload;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Msg));
end;
```